# Does a differential equation of the form $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)=0$ exists whose solution is $y=x^8$ and $P(x),Q(x)$ are continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Does a differential equation of the form $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)=0$ exists whose solution is $y=x^8$ and $P(x)$, $Q(x)$ are continuous functions?

Comment: Got something from an answer below? You have been remarkably silent about it, especially seeing the (explicit or implicit) puzzlement shared by both answerers...

Answer (score 3):

Since $y=x^8$ satisfies $y'' - 56x^6 = 0$, the answer is yes.  Are you perhaps intending to ask a different Question?

Answer (score 3):

For **every** function $y_0$ of class $C^2$, there exists a differential equation $y''+Py'+Q=0$ such that $y=y_0$ is solution and $P$ and $Q$ are continuous functions: choose **any** $P$ and $Q=-y_0''-Py_0'$.